# Parse JSON for Cyberpower UPS into InfluxDB/Grafana

Tags: javascript, json, bash, influxdb, grafana

I'm trying to parse JSON from my Cyberpower UPS agent (for importing data into InfluxDB/Grafana). I'm able to parse everything I want with the exception of the battery state. Seen below, if the UPS is disconnected from utility power, the state is **"Discharging"**, but if it's connected, then the value contains a comma, **"Normal, Fully Charged"**.... I'm unable to find a way to parse the data knowing that the value may or may not have a comma in it. If the value is "Discharging", then it works fine, but because of the comma in **"Normal, Fully Charged"**, the grep result is **"Normal** (obviously missing the ending quotation).

JSON for single value:

```
"battery":{"state":"Discharging",
```

JSON for value with comma and space:

```
"battery":{"state":"Normal, Fully Charged",
```

My curl/greb. Is it possible to do this to pull a value that may or may not have a comma in the value I want? If so, what am I doing wrong?

```
curl http://10.0.1.61:3052/agent/ppbe.js/init_status.js | grep -oP '(?<="battery":{"state":)[^,]*' | head -1
```

Full .js page when discharging:

```
var ppbeJsObj = {
    "status": {
        "communicationAvaiable": true,
        "onlyPhaseArch": false,
        "utility": {
            "state": "Blackout",
            "stateWarning": true,
            "voltage": "0",
            "frequency": "60.00",
            "voltages": null,
            "currents": null,
            "frequencies": null,
            "powerFactors": null
        },
        "bypass": {
            "state": "Normal",
            "stateWarning": false,
            "voltage": null,
            "current": null,
            "frequency": null,
            "voltages": null,
            "currents": null,
            "frequencies": null,
            "powerFactors": null
        },
        "output": {
            "state": "Normal",
            "stateWarning": false,
            "voltage": "120.0",
            "frequency": null,
            "load": 58,
            "watt": 522,
            "current": null,
            "outputLoadWarning": false,
            "outlet1": null,
            "outlet2": null,
            "activePower": null,
            "apparentPower": null,
            "reactivePower": null,
            "voltages": null,
            "currents": null,
            "frequencies": null,
            "powerFactors": null,
            "loads": null,
            "activePowers": null,
            "apparentPowers": null,
            "reactivePowers": null,
            "emergencyOff": null,
            "batteryExhausted": null
        },
        "battery": {
            "state": "Discharging",
            "stateWarning": true,
            "voltage": null,
            "capacity": 99,
            "runtimeFormat": 1,
            "runtimeFormatWarning": false,
            "runtimeHour": 0,
            "runtimeMinute": 20,
            "chargetimeFormat": null,
            "chargetimeHour": null,
            "chargetimeMinute": null,
            "temperatureCelsius": null,
            "highVoltage": null,
            "lowVoltage": null,
            "highCurrent": null,
            "lowCurrent": null
        },
        "upsSystem": {
            "state": "Normal",
            "stateWarning": false,
            "temperatureCelsius": null,
            "temperatureFahrenheit": null,
            "maintenanceBreak": null,
            "systemFaultDueBypass": null,
            "systemFaultDueBypassFan": null,
            "originalHardwareFaultCode": "0x8080"
        },
        "modules": null,
        "deviceId": 0
    }
};
```

Comment: See: https://community.openhab.org/t/8334 (I believe this is the same question.)

Comment: Do you need to parse JSON (use `jq '.battery.state'`) or JavaScript. You are giving a JavaScript snippet as the output, which is not the same thing at all as JSON.

Comment: @chepner - I believe the aim here is to extract the object from the JavaScript, then parse that.

Comment: That's a horrifying design decision on the part of the UPS manufacturer.

Comment: @eptesicus - Are you trying to parse this JavaScript in bash? - This might then be of use to you. (https://denlab.io/the-easy-way-to-pull-ups-statistics-using-cyberpower-panel/)

Answer (score 1):

### A bash solution:

You could do something like this:

```
curl http://10.0.1.61:3052/agent/ppbe.js/init_status.js | \
grep -oP '(?<="battery":\s*{)([^}]+)(?=})' | \
grep -oP '(?<="state": ")([^"]+)(?=")'
```

Breaking this down:

First, the regex.

`(?<=)` is a positive look behind group. so `(?<=aa)bb` will match any `bb` that is preceded by `aa`.

`(?=)` is a positive look ahead group, so, `bb(?=aa)` will match any `bb` that is followed by `aa`.

Now, the command,

Get the file: `curl http://10.0.1.61:3052/agent/ppbe.js/init_status.js | \`

Find the `battery` section: `grep -oP '(?<="battery":\s*{)([^}]+)(?=})' | \`
This will convert it to this sort of thing:

```
"state": "Normal, Fully Charged",
"stateWarning": true,
"voltage": null,
"capacity": 99,
"runtimeFormat": 1,
"runtimeFormatWarning": false,
"runtimeHour": 0,
"runtimeMinute": 20,
"chargetimeFormat": null,
"chargetimeHour": null,
"chargetimeMinute": null,
"temperatureCelsius": null,
"highVoltage": null,
"lowVoltage": null,
"highCurrent": null,
"lowCurrent": null
```

Find the `state` key/value: `grep -oP '(?<="state": ")([^"]+)(?=")'`
Then this one will return the value:

```
Normal, Fully Charged
```

For more advanced JSON you could do something like:

```
curl http://10.0.1.61:3052/agent/ppbe.js/init_status.js | \
grep -oP '(?<="battery":\s*{)(([^{}]++|(?1))*)(?=})' | \
grep -oP '(?<="state": ")([^"]+)(?=")'
```

See (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/147664) for how this works.

---

### A JS solution:

You could strip the variable declaration and semi-colon, then parse it like normal JSON.

```
// Here 'input' is your 'init_status.js' string
input = JSON.parse(input.replace(
    /(?:^[\s\S]*?(?={))|(?:;[^;]*?$)/g,
    ""
))
```

If you also need to 'get' the file then you could do this:

```
const http = require('http');
http.get(
    'http://10.0.1.61:3052/agent/ppbe.js/init_status.js',
    response => {
        let body = '';

        // Read the data.
        response.on('data', chunk => {body += chunk});

        // The file is complete, now we can use it.
        response.on('end', () => {
            const data = JSON.parse(
                body.replace(
                    /(?:^[\s\S]*?(?={))|(?:;[^;]*?$)/g,
                    ""
                )
            );

            // This logs the entire JSON object.
            console.log(data);

            // Getting the 'battery state'
            console.log(data.status.battery.state);
        });
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
grep -P -o '(?<="battery":{"state":")[a-zA-Z, ]+'
```

Regards!

EDIT : Edited due to OPs comment.

```
$ cat test.txt
var ppbeJsObj={"status":{"communicationAvaiable":true,
"onlyPhaseArch":false,
"utility":{"state":"Blackout",
"stateWarning":true,
"voltage":"0",
"frequency":"60.00",
"voltages":null,
"currents":null,
"frequencies":null,
"powerFactors":null},
"bypass":{"state":"Normal",
"stateWarning":false,
"voltage":null,
"current":null,
"frequency":null,
"voltages":null,
"currents":null,
"frequencies":null,
"powerFactors":null},
"output":{"state":"Normal",
"stateWarning":false,
"voltage":"120.0",
"frequency":null,
"load":58,
"watt":522,
"current":null,
"outputLoadWarning":false,
"outlet1":null,
"outlet2":null,
"activePower":null,
"apparentPower":null,
"reactivePower":null,
"voltages":null,
"currents":null,
"frequencies":null,
"powerFactors":null,
"loads":null,
"activePowers":null,
"apparentPowers":null,
"reactivePowers":null,
"emergencyOff":null,
"batteryExhausted":null},
"battery":{"state":"Discharging",
"stateWarning":true,
"voltage":null,
"capacity":99,
"runtimeFormat":1,
"runtimeFormatWarning":false,
"runtimeHour":0,
"runtimeMinute":20,
"chargetimeFormat":null,
"chargetimeHour":null,
"chargetimeMinute":null,
"temperatureCelsius":null,
"highVoltage":null,
"lowVoltage":null,
"highCurrent":null,
"lowCurrent":null},
"upsSystem":{"state":"Normal",
"stateWarning":false,
"temperatureCelsius":null,
"temperatureFahrenheit":null,
"maintenanceBreak":null,
"systemFaultDueBypass":null,
"systemFaultDueBypassFan":null,
"originalHardwareFaultCode":"0x8080"},
"modules":null,
"deviceId":0}};

$ grep -P -o '(?<="battery":{"state":")[a-zA-Z, ]+' test.txt
Discharging
```

Comment: This works according to regexr.com, but when performing the action on my server, nothing is returned. **curl http://10.0.1.61:3052/agent/ppbe.js/init_status.js | grep -oP '(?<="battery":{"state":)[a-zA-Z, ]+'**

Comment: @eptesicus Add the -P and -o flags as shown on my edition.